# Matplotlib subplots: Remove subplots when not plotted while aligning width

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot subplots for each individual, each with varying number of subplots, and any individual having a maximum subplots of 5. So the `len(arr)` below can be anywhere from 0 to 5.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr = np.array([[x,y], [x,y]]) # len of 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=5,figsize=(12,4))
for i in range(min(len(arr),5)):
    axs[i].plot(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])
```

[image]

In the above example, the individual has 2 subplots. How do I remove the subplots that do not have any values while maintaining the width of the 2 subplots? And if possible, align them in the center of the "canvas".

[image]

Comment: Why not set the number of columns equal the length of array, i.e. `ncols=len(arr)`?

Comment: Please read the question: ***while maintaining the width of the 2 subplots***. Setting it to `ncols=len(arr)` just fills the N subplots to the entire figure width. In the above example, the 2 subplots' widths are consistent with the 5 subplots above

Comment: You can just do `axs[i].remove()`, but that won't center your filled axes.  If you really need that, you can go in and change the axes positions (using `axs[i].get_position` and `axs[i].set_position`)

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be edited to:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr = np.array([[x,y], [x,y]]) # len of 2

# or
# arr = np.array([[x,y], [x,y], [2*x, y]]) # len of 3

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=len(arr),figsize=(12,4))
for i in range(min(len(arr), len(arr))):
    axs[i].plot(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])
```

**Edit**

To force the width of each subplot to a constant value, add these lines of code to the above.

```
# continued
plt.draw()
for eax in axs:
    # this id good for figure with 5 or less subplots
    p11 = eax.get_position()
    p11_new = [p11.x0, p11.y0, 1/6.8, p11.height]
    eax.set_position(p11_new)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The width of individual subplots have to be consistent with the 5 subplots, even if there are less than 5 subplots

Comment: @TYL The answer is updated. Any other comment?